# NativeWind View with padding left

Tags: react-native, nativewind

I have a strange padding on left when using `View` inside other `View`

I'm using `nativewind` `2.0.11`

```js
<View className="flex-col items-center justify-center flex-grow gap-2 bg-blue-400">
    <View className="flex-row justify-between w-1/2 gap-2 bg-red-400 ">
        <Text>+</Text>
        <Text>4</Text>
        <Text>-</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

This give me :

[image]

You can see, before the "+", i get a left padding

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs with v2

Try this

```
<View className="flex-col items-center justify-center flex-grow bg-blue-400" style={{ gap: 8 }}>
    <View className="flex-row justify-between w-1/2 bg-red-400 " style={{ gap: 8 }}>
        <Text>+</Text>
        <Text>4</Text>
        <Text>-</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/622